# Want to make a slicer of week days in Excel, which will show week days

Tags: excel

Want to make a slicer of weekdays

i have the table below and want to make a slicer of weekdays. I have a slicer of hour and dates. but also want to make a slicer of weekdays e.g(Monday, Tuesday etc)

```
{Full Date      Date       WeekDays Time
25-Jul-19 16:00 25-Jul-19   -   16
25-Jul-19 16:00 25-Jul-19   -   16
25-Jul-19 16:00 25-Jul-19   -   16
25-Jul-19 17:00 25-Jul-19   -   17
25-Jul-19 17:00 25-Jul-19   -   17
25-Jul-19 17:00 25-Jul-19   -   17
25-Jul-19 18:00 25-Jul-19   -   18
25-Jul-19 18:00 25-Jul-19   -   18
25-Jul-19 18:00 25-Jul-19   -   18
25-Jul-19 19:00 25-Jul-19   -   19
25-Jul-19 19:00 25-Jul-19   -   19
25-Jul-19 19:00 25-Jul-19   -   19
25-Jul-19 20:00 25-Jul-19   -   20}
```

Comment: Please include an actual question :)

Comment: Are you typing in a string or are you selecting a cell? LIke `=WEEKDAY(A2)`? You will need to make sure the input is a date so make sure your input is. Note that some cells can appear to have a date although it is actually a string. You can google how to easily confirm if a cell is date or string

Answer (score 0):

> WEEKDAY(Date, Return_Type)

You can use the above formula to return a 1:1 mapping of day of week to number. You can modify the `Return_Type` argument to customize the output (For example: should 1 start at Sun or Mon)

---

Create a helper column with above formula and use this field as your pivot slicer

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with the formula `=WEEKDAY([put your date cells here], [pick which type you want])`

For the second part of the formula, it will give you options asking whether you want to have the weekday count start on Monday, Sunday, etc.

You can create a table and nest this formula inside a `vlookup` to actually pull the name of the day. Once you've done this, resize the pivottable to include the new column and create the slicer similar to how you did before.

To create the nested formula, first make a table with the days laid out how'd you like. For this we're starting on Sunday.

```
Column1 | Column2
1       | Sunday
2       | Monday
Etc.    | Etc.
```

`=vlookup(weekday([Date Cell],1),[Table],2,0)`

Put the cell reference to the date for `Date Cell` & put the full locked table reference for the table you just created for `Table`.